# Dumbing down a relatively difficult function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function in a code snippet differently than how it was written. It's a program that sends HTML5 API notifications to users who are logged in on the page as well. This code is fairly hard for me to understand as I'm still fairly new with javascript so I can't really tell how I can tweak it. I could use some help in that with the below code.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){

              list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                if(!e.target.id) return;

                e.target.className = 'icon-oi';
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    e.target.className = '';
                }, 3000);

                pubnub.publish({
                    channel : channel, 
                    message : {from: username, to: e.target.id}, 
                });
            }, false);
    });
```

I'm simply just trying to have it so that it's not dependent on having to click the "list" target for you to send a notification, but that you send the notification to all targets on the click of a simple html button. 
This is so that you don't have to click on each individual target.

As you can see that's what I'm trying to do with the first line. That's the extent of how much I can tweak it without causing some error. Could anyone help me out with this?

I can understand that having just this snippet won't give you the total picture so please, feel free to visit the page where I got it from. Here's the [link](https://dev.opera.com/articles/web-notifications-pubnub/).

Comment: Right now, your code adds a new click event handler to `list` every time you click on `#myBtn`. The part of the code that's sending out the notifications is the `pubnub.publish({ ... })`. Have you tried just using that section of the code? Also, `e.target.id` refers to the ID of the `list` element. What do you think the `id` value of `myBtn` is?

Comment: myBtn is simply the name of the button <button> id="myBtn">click</button Having that code the way it looks now only adds another conditional statement saying the notifications are only sent once the e.target.id is clicked if the myBtn button is clicked.  Also, no i've tried using just the pubnub.publish({...}) portion of it - to no avail. The code is in that link I've offered, it leads to a whole github so you can tweak around with that too if you fancy. By the way, on a totally different issue, how can I make code I post in these comments look like you just did in yours? Ctrl + K won't do it.

Comment: `myBtn` is the ID of the element. So when you click `myBtn` then `e.target.id === "myBtn"`. Consider how that plays into the existing code. When you say you tried just the `pubnub` part but it didn't work, did you [get an error in your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log#t=201610122029241634408) Also, to format code in comments, use backticks. `\`code\``.

Comment: It'll say e isn't defined. This is the code how it looks like then. I wouldn't know what it'd need to look like.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){

            pubnub.publish({
                channel : channel, 
                message : {from: username, to: e.target.id}, 
            });
        }, false);
};` This is how it'd be set up giving that e isn't defined error.

Comment: Check out `list.addEventListener('click', function(e) { ...`. Notice how they're choosing to accept a parameter named `e`, which is the click event object. Could you change your click handler to also accept a click event object?

Comment: Right, so I have to pass e right in the button's click handler like so? `document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(e){...}` That does clear any error but it's not what's allowing me to send notifications either. In fact the button just does nothing

Comment: So you've got code similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L48zuumm/) and absolutely nothing is happening? What do you expect to happen? If you have multiple users, each user likely has their own ID (hence the `e.target.id`). Make sure you're sending the correct ID. Right now you're going to be sending `myBtn`. To figure out where you get that ID is out of the scope of Stack Overflow. You'll need to hunt that down yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying. I was hoping it wouldn't be too difficult to obtain all the instances of ids so there's no need to select which target to click on. I will have to look into that yes. But thanks to your help you've gotten me along my way so, thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry I couldn't help more.